# How to save environment variable from Terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, environment-variables

I am trying to save the PATH environment variable from the Terminal running on a Ubuntu system.

I typed in the following however it does not get saved.

```
export PATH=/home/david/Komodo-Edit-6/bin/:$PATH
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add that line to `~/.bashrc`, or the appropriate configuration file for your shell.

Comment: To you mean this `export PATH=/home/david/Komodo-Edit-6/bin/:$PATH ~/.bashrc`, because it doesn't work. I am using the bash shell.

Comment: @David No. I mean to edit the file `~/.bashrc` and add the `export` statement to its contents.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually edited `/root/.bash_profile` and it now works.

Comment: @David `.bash_profile` is, by default, only loaded for login shells. It likely won't work if you start `bash` yourself.

Comment: @Daniel: In the specific case of appending/prepending to `$PATH` environment variable, the *profile* file is even better, because 1) the new value is exported to other processes anyway, and 2) if it was in *bashrc*, then you could end up with the same directory 3 or 4 times.

Comment: @grawity I read that `.profile` is ignored if `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` exist and don't load it explicitly. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Daniel: In login shell mode, *bash* looks for `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `.profile` (in that order) and only uses the first one found. (See manual page of bash(1), section "INVOCATION".) In my previous comment, by saying "profile file" I was referring to all three files.

Comment: @Daniel: For completeness: In *non-login* mode, *bash* only looks for `.bashrc`.

Comment: @grawity That's what I read too (although I didn't really understand your comment, as should be obvious), and thought I remembered `.bash_profile` usually loading `.bashrc` on Linux, so it seemed the best choice.